# How to index an array of element in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 1.4.3 and I'm trying to create an automated "filler" for the database.
The idea is to use this website http://beta.json-generator.com/BhxCdZ6 to generate a random set of data and push it in an index of Elasticsearch.

For interfacing with Elasticsearch, I am using Elasticsearch for Java API mixed with the Elasticsearch web API.

I managed to push one user per time simply copy-pasting the information excluding the **[** and **]** characters and creating a shell script that calls

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/users/' -d '{
    "name": {
      "first": "Dickerson",
      "last": "Wood"
    }, etc...
```

If I try to copy a full block composed of 3 people and try to push the data with the same script

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/geocon/users/' -d '[
  {
    "name": {
      "first": "Dickerson",
      "last": "Wood"
    }, etc ... 
]
  }'
```

The error returned is :

**org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Malformed content, must start with an object**

How would you solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing brace wrapping the item:

```
  [
    {
    "name": {
      "first": "Dickerson",
      "last": "Wood"
    }, etc.
  ]
```

You can validate your JSON e.g. via http://jsonlint.com/.

Also, try taking a look at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: Thank you for your helping, but if I paste the JSON generated (actually, the vector of jsons) the website says **Valid JSON** even without the **{** in the outer level

Comment: If you insert the missing } before the end of the array, yes. I took your second example, removing  `, etc ...` (not the brace!) and it returns an error because you are missing the closing brace for for Object with the name property. I updated my answer.

Comment: You're right, my typo. Unfortunately, the problem remains